# common license for intelliJ and WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

is that possible to have a common license for both intelliJ and WebStorm IDEs?  I know these are separate products, but I couldn't finy any information whether the license can be combined or not. My company do have intelliJ already, but we need WebStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Educational license is using all JetBrains product.
If you use License Server, maybe same license for IntelliJ IDEA and WebStorm.
But if your company had single product licese, not intergration other license.

For fast processing your question,
send a mail to JetBrains sales part. [sales@jetbrains.com](http://sales@jetbrains.com)